# error in downloading android sdk plugin in Netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: android, netbeans-7

While trying to install android sdk on Netbeans 7.1.1, it shows the following error message: the link Unable to connect to the Android development kit provider because of Zero sized file reported at http://kenai.com/downloads/nbandroid/updatecenter/updates.xml, how can i solve it?
Where can i get the source file?

Answer (score 1):

You need use  Netbeans 7.2 . I thinking is working with 7.1.1 :

http://nbandroid.org/release72/updates/updates.xml

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you try the SDK bundle provided in the developer site? Then you don't want to install Android to Eclipse.

In this case, did you connect the ADT to Eclipse successfully?

Comment: yes....now i am using eclipse....but since i already doing another java project on netbeans.....it would be a lot more easier for me to use netbeans

Comment: i think we cant use netbeans smoothly with android.. better u stay with eclipse :) al d bst.